# Opening a new JFrame Windows for a different swing class

Tags: java, swing

I'm having issues with opening a different swing class on jbutton click. In the action listener I'm putting the following

```
JButton searchComputerButton = new JButton("Search");
    searchComputerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             MISMain misMain = new MISMain();
             misMain.setVisible(true);
             etc...
```

but I'm getting an red squiggly error on misMain.setVisible(true) and I'm unsure why.
It says "The method setVisible(boolean) is undefined for the type MISMain"
Both classes are in the same package in Eclipse and it recognizes MISMain class so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error. Let me know if you need additional information. Any help is appreciated.

First part of MISMain as requested

```
public MISMain() throws IOException {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     * 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void initialize() throws IOException {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.getContentPane().setForeground(Color.RED);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 658, 618);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.setTitle("MIS Advanced Computerers");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\anoc5f\\Desktop\\Output.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");
        JButton searchComputerButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchComputerButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String line;
                BufferedWriter bw = null;
                BufferedWriter writer = null;
                try {
                    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


                String s = null;

                Process p = null;
                /*
                 * try { // p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                 * "cmd /c start c:\\computerQuery.bat computerName"); } catch
                 * (IOException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 * e1.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
                try {

                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c:\\computerQuery.bat");

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
                StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                        .getInputStream()));

                try {

                    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                        System.out.println(line);

                        // textArea.append(line);

                        String dn = "CN=FDCD111304,OU=Workstations,OU=SIM,OU=Accounts,DC=FL,DC=NET";
                        LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
                        String commonName = (String) ldapName.getRdn(
                                ldapName.size() - 1).getValue();

                    }
                    ComputerQuery.sendParam();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                } catch (InvalidNameException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } finally

                {
                    try {
                        fw.close();

                    }

                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {

                    in.close();

                } catch (IOException e1) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }

                ComputerQuery.sendParam();


            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post code for `MISMain` at least a few starting lines. The error basically says there is no setVisible method in `MISMain` class. It seems that `MISMain` class is not extending `JFrame`. Instead you may be having it as a field.

Comment: I updated the code above and added a part of MISMain that's relevant

Comment: Also I updated MISMain based on suggestion to public class MISMain extends JFrame { and it opens a new gui, but it's blank and not the MISMain Class

Comment: Just extending `JFrame` will not help. That will not display frame you created using `frame = new JFrame();` code. Instead, provide a public method in `MISMain` called `setVisible()` where you actually do a `frame.setVisible(true)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a method to `MSMain`, which will make `frame` visible:

```
public void setVisible(boolean input){
    frame.setVisible(input);
}
```

without extending `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comments, you can not call `setVisible` method on `MISMain` as that class does not have `setVisible` method. Rather, it is part of `JFrame`.

There are two solutions possible.

One is MISMain **IS-A** JFrame. That implementation would look like this. Note: Since MISMain itself is the JFrame, you do not have to have a frame member variable.

```
class MISMain extends JFrame {
   public MISMain() throws IOException {
     getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
     getContentPane().setForeground(Color.RED);
     setBounds(100, 100, 658, 618);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     getContentPane().setLayout(null);
     setTitle("MIS Advanced Computerers");
     setResizable(false);
     //All other code.
   }
}
```

Then from `actionPerformed` you can create a new instance of MISMain and invoke `setVisible(true);` on it, and frame will be visible.

Second approach is MISMain **HAS-A** JFrame. This implementation would essentially look like your current implementation. But then you will have to add some code that will make the frame visible.

```
class MISMain {
  JFrame frame;
  //... other field
  //..all the implementations you have
  //Now add a method like : show() as below

  public void show() {
   frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

At least in the case of Swing windows, IS-A approach is more intuitive than HAS-A.

Comment: This isn't referencing the other class. I need it to open the class called MISControlPanel which is in the same package as MISMain.

Comment: Then you should have a way to call `setVisible(true)` on MISControlPanel from the client (event handler code)

Answer (score -1):

MISMain is not a frame - right?

so you can not set it visible. add a getter for the "frame" (and make it member). You can set frames visible.

Comment: Try giving more info in your answer. Why would this work?